# navigation destination xxxx is unknown to this navcontroller in tab layout

Tags: android, mvvm

I was tried to navigate to another fragment from tablayout, at this time getting  this issue  " **navigation destination  xxxx  is unknown to this navcontroller in tab layout** "

view?.findNavController()?.navigate(R.id.action_homeFragment_to_giveOpinion)

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting it to prevent multiple clicks,